# Correct way to add virtual attributes to a rails active_record model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

I want to add virtual fields / attributes to a rails model and have it included in the attributes that get returned by default when I call `@my_model`

Assuming I have a model called Booking that has a `start_at` and `end_at` that are both datetime fields.

```ruby
@booking = Booking.new(start_at: DateTime.now, end_at: DateTime.now + 4.hours)
```

When I print the booking or say render it as json etc I get the following:

```ruby
p @booking

# Booking
id => 1,
start_at => Wed, 30 Nov 2022 10:50:20 +0800,
end_at => Wed, 30 Nov 2022 14:50:22 +0800
```

All standard so far.

Now I want to add virtual attributes called `start_date, start_time, end_date, end_time` that will be derived from the `start_at` and `end_at` fields

So I add them as attributes to the class:

```ruby
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :start_date, :start_time, :end_date, :end_time 

  def start_time
    self.start_at.strftime('%H:%M')
  end

  ...etc

end
```

so now I print the model again:

```ruby
@booking

# Booking
id => 1,
start_at => Wed, 30 Nov 2022 10:50:20 +0800,
end_at => Wed, 30 Nov 2022 14:50:22 +0800
```

The virtual attributes are not shown.

However if I add them to the attributes method I can call `@booking.attributes`:

```ruby
class Booking < ApplicationRecord

attr_accessor :start_date, :start_time, :end_date, :end_time 

  def start_time
    self.start_at.strftime('%H:%M')
  end


  def attributes
    super.merge({'start_time' => start_ime})
  end

end

@booking.attributes

# Booking
id => 1,
start_at => Wed, 30 Nov 2022 10:50:20 +0800,
end_at => Wed, 30 Nov 2022 14:50:22 +0800
start_time => '10:50'
...etc
```

So my question is how can i modify what attributes get returned by default, so I don't have to call .attributes on the model every time? I would like to just do `render json: @booking` and have all attributes (including the virtual ones) included.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I would like to just do render json: @booking and have all attributes (including the virtual ones) included."

Would a serializer be of use here?

Comment: @Viktor Do you mean add a serialized column in the db? The problem then would be I have the date recorded in 2 places and no longer one source of truth.

Also Im very curious how to achieve the above, it must be do-able...

Comment: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Comment: What Viktor may suggest is to implement these methods at the serializer level, which makes sense to me as it's the same data formated differently. AMS 0.10 isn't maintain but is still usable (as long as you don't expect specific serializations, such as JSONAPI). Docs are messy, but you may find what your want in this section https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/serializers.md

Answer (score 1):

You're falling victim to a very common Ruby beginner misconception. `attr_accessor` doesn't actually declare attributes because Ruby doesn't actually have declared attributes/properties like for example Java does.

Ruby just has *instance variables* and all that `attr_accessor :start_date` does is to use metaprogramming to create `start_date` and `start_date=` getter and setter methods that expose the instance variable to the outside.

That doesn't actually mean that Ruby is keeping track that the Booking class has a `start_date` property - the instance variable doesn't even exist until you set it and the setter/getter are just plain old methods. Sometimes these are lazily refered to as "virtual attributes" but its actually far from the truth.

Ruby does however provide the basic building blocks needed to build any kind of attribute system you want. Rails has [`ActiveModel::Attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Attributes/ClassMethods.html) which is the base API and [`ActiveRecord::Attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html) which is specialized implementation for database table backed models.

Attibutes are a Rails constuct - not a part of the language.

```ruby
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :start_at, type: :datetime
end
```

```ruby
irb(main):005:0> Booking.new.as_json
=> {"id"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil, "start_at"=>nil}
```

Unlike `attr_accessor` this not just creates setters and getters but it also updates a class instance variable which keeps track of the attributes of the class. That's how Rails knows to include "start_at" when you call `to_json`.

If you want to add a method which is not an attribute when rendering JSON use the `methods:` option:

```ruby
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :start_at, type: :datetime

  def start_time
    start_at.strftime('%H:%M')
  end
end
```

```
irb(main):013:0> Booking.new(start_at: Time.now).as_json(methods: [:start_time])
=> {"id"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil, "start_at"=>"2022-11-30T16:12:02.188+01:00", "start_time"=>"16:12"}
```

```
render json: @booking, methods: [:start_at]
```

[But, overriding `as_json` in model or doing complex JSON rendering in the controller are both known anti-patterns.](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/better-serialization-less-as-json) Its often a good idea to move JSON serialization into its own layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by overriding the `as_json` method for that model:

```rb
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  def as_json(*)
    super(methods: %i(start_date start_time end_date end_time))
  end
end
```

As @max pointed out in another answer, it's a better idea to move the "serialization" stuff to its own layer for large projects. You can use for example:

- https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
- https://okuramasafumi.github.io/alba
- https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer
- https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers (seems a bit outdated nowadays)

But for simple use-cases, overriding the `as_json` method is probably just good enough.